# Need to change the apache default home page

Tags: apache

I am new to apache.I installed apache in my windows, I am having my own html page with css.I want to set this page as my default apache home page and instead of typing http://localhost:8080, i have to type http://vignesh to view my home page. 
How to do this..Guide me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your question is split into 2 things: The ability to use http://vignesh as opposed to http://localhost:8080, and the option to change the default home page.

In order to get the url that you want working, you need to modify a file in windows (assuming you're on windows 7) do the following:

1. Launch notepad (or any other text editor) with administrative privileges
2. Open the hosts file located at: C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
3. Add the following entry to it: 127.0.0.1    vignesh

In order to change the default page you need to change the apache configuration.

1. Open httpd.conf in your favorite text editor
2. Locate the property called DirectoryIndex. Change it to the page that you want.

I hope that was helpful.

Comment: Thanks. where is httpd.conf file located?

Comment: @hrenvadro thank you! @vignesh it's usually found where you installed apache. If you're in doubt search for it, it's called: httpd.conf

Comment: Thanks. But still i have to type http://vignesh:8080 instead of http://vignesh to view my default page.How to do this. I searched for httpd.conf but couldnt find it.can you tell me the exact directory where it is located in apache

Comment: You need to tell Apache to listen to port 80 as opposed to 8080. I personally keep it 8080 as port 80 is usually used by another program (Skype or IIS for example). If you decided to change it, go to httpd.conf and change `Listen` option. `Listen 80`. However, make sure that only apache is using this port or apache won't start.

Comment: I couldnt find the file httpd.conf in apache directory?.Under which directory it will present

Comment: vignesh, how did you install apache? Stand alone installation or part of a full stack like xampp?

Comment: It should be available under the `conf` folder.

Answer (score 0):

When you type an address in a browser, the browser relies on the operating system to *resolve* it. Only once it has been resolved, a request is sent to the actual server (in this case, your apache installation).

Because of this, you can't alter how the "server" part is resolved through apache itself: it is your Windows system which handles that and, if appropriate (this is, if it resolves to `localhost` at the port where your apache is listening), forwards it to apache.

So, you need to alter how *Windows*, rather than apache, resolves that address. Fortunately, for your situation, it's relatively easy to tweak, if you know what to look for (and I am telling you here, so you know ;) ):

Open the file `%SystemRoot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` on a plain text editor, such as notepad (`%SystemRoot%` is window's base installation path, such as `C:\Windows` or `C:\WinNT`), and add a line like this at the end:

```
127.0.0.1       vignesh
```

Comment: Thanks. But still i have to type http://vignesh:8080/ instead of http://vignesh.How to do this. I searched for httpd.conf but couldnt find it.can you tell me the exact directory where it is located in apache

Comment: No need to duplicate the comment ;) As Ali mentioned, you would need to change the apache port to 80 for this to work as you want; and here is _why_: When you type an address without a explicit port on the browser, all browsers default to port `80`; if you want to connect to a service listening on a different port, you need to specify the port. Or the other way around, make the service listen at port 80 so the browser's default will work to reach it.